# What prevents device files from being executed?

Tags: permissions, linux-kernel

I'm writing a kernel character device driver for which I've implemented the `fops.read`, and the `FIONREAD` (`0x541B`) ioctl. The data returned by `read` is an ELF executable. `ls -l` confirms that the device has `r-x` permissions, and both of the following commands allow me to execute the contained ELF binary:

```
# cp /dev/foo0 /tmp/bar && /tmp/bar
-or-
# cat /dev/foo0 > /tmp/bar && /tmp/bar
foo_open
foo_ioctl 0x0000541B
foo_read size=131072 off=0
foo_ioctl 0x0000541B
foo_read size=131072 off=13096
foo_release
Hello from /tmp/bar!
...
```

Note that the kernel messages indicate the various driver messages that are called.  When I try to run the device directly, however, I get an error:

```
# /dev/foo0
foo_open
foo_release
/bin/sh: 6: /dev/foo0: Permission denied
```

What check might be causing the permissions error, and is it possible to override it without fundamentally breaking linux?  I'm using the 4.18.3 kernel with a minimal sysroot image.

Comment: I think you'd be better served by asking this on [so], but at minimum I'd guess you need mmap support for exec to work. If you'd like to have your question moved, flag it as "in need of moderator intervention" and ask (in the text box) the moderator to move it to Stack Overflow. [unix.se] mainly focuses on administering and using Unix/Linux systems, not kernel programming.

Comment: I oppose this migration.  This is a question about Unix (and, really, a question about using Unix *from the command line*) that happens to mention software development as context.  This is not a question about programming.

Comment: As others replied, the kernel checks for a regular file on `execve` syscall (and that makes sense.) You can still consider providing an ELF binary from the kernel, just expose it as a virtual file under a kernel filesystem such as /proc or /sys. You might also find interesting this article about user mode helpers (initially considered for bpfilter) which tries to do something like this (and more, since it also considers spawning the process from the kernel): https://lwn.net/Articles/755919/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`man 2 execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

> **EACCES** The file or a script interpreter is not a regular file.

The Linux kernel only allows regular files to be executed, not character devices or any other special files. The kernel does that check [in the `do_open_execat` function in fs/exec.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/exec.c?h=0238df646e6224016a45505d2c111a24669ebe21#n858):

```c
if (!S_ISREG(file_inode(file)->i_mode))
    goto exit;
```

You can rebuild the kernel without that check if you really want, but it's probably there for a good reason.

Comment: Dang! You beat me by 11 seconds!

Comment: This exactly. I was able to avoid hitting this check by masquerading as a regular file in `foo_open` if `FMODE_EXEC` was set in `filp->f_flags`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you’re not (ever) allowed to `exec` device files. 
The [`execve` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) lists

> **`EACCES`**
>
>   The file or a script interpreter is not a regular file.

in the [ERRORS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#ERRORS) section.